# Not able to acess both frontend and backend ..!

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, backend, frontend-error

Am new to magento using 1.9.2,Suddenly am not able to acess my site both in frontend and backend.It showing Error msg like these

`There has been an error processing your request`

`SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'aerowysg_indianskart'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I also flushed `var/cache` `var/session` through Ftp,
I also seen `app/etc/local.xml` all details are good.I dont know what to do next!! Can anyone help me please,I have access to C-panel and ftp.

*NOTE*:I doesn't download any extensions,No changes made in blocks/modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database username and password seem to be either incorrect or do not have the correct privileges for localhost.

Try ssh into your server

```
mysql -u aerowysg_indianskart -h localhost -p
```

then enter the password at the prompt. If you can not connect then try log in to C-panel and follow the instruction below

[Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' while attempting to grant privileges. How do I grant privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484722/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-while-attempting-to-grant-privileges)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I doesn't tried ssh,am new to Magento but i learn and try what you said.Again thanks for your reference source.

Comment: Is your issue now resolved?

Comment: Not yet..Trying it in c panel by changing user name or by creating new user with full previlages for that Database

Comment: Problem solved..I renamed that user name,and tried in `local.xml`,its worked..I got that idea after seeing your reference link..Thank you R.S,You Rocked